# How to translate a pcre (php) regex pattern in bash?

Tags: php, regex, bash

I have the following regex pattern that is working nicely in php

```
/(^((?!thumb).)*\.jpg)/
```

My task is to translate this regex in bash, the ideea is to find all the `.jpg` files from a directory (recursively) that do not contains the `thumb` word in the file path.

I use a structure like this:

`find /folder/path -regex '(^((?!thumb).)*\.jpg)'`

But i have zero results ? Is there something wrong with my regex in bash?

Comment: Try with `find /folder/path -regextype posix-extended -iregex '^((?!thumb).)*\\.jpg'`

Comment: @ThomasAyoub None of the regex types support PCRE only features.

Comment: I got `Invalid preceding regular expression`

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru To reiterate my above comment in a different way, you cannot use PCRE regex with find.

Comment: General advice: don't try to "translate" a regex flavor to an other (same thing for a code written in language to a code written in an other language). If you follow that way, you will have a headache and obtain bad results. The good approach is: "what does the pattern/code?" *(as opposed to "how is it written?" or "what is the technique used?")* => "how to obtain the same result with this language/regex flavor/tool?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -not -iname "*thumb*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use negative lookahead with `find` since it's a POSIX regex. You may use this workaround:

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' | grep -v "thumb"
```

Which will list all `jpg` files then, thanks to `grep` exclude all files containing `thumb`

Answer (score 1):

Think the best you are going to get with find is using two different criteria instead of a single regex

```
find . -name '*.jpg' ! -regex '.*thumb.*'
```